# iPhone 3G won't boot

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, startup, jailbreak

I have an iPhone 3G that has worked well in the past, but it was put away for several years (after I got an iPhone 4s), and when I took it out again it wouldn't boot. It was jailbroken some years ago (it is preowned), and it boots with a pineapple with the bite out (instead of the classic apple), see image below.

[image: pineapple]

The phone won't boot past this screen.

I have photos on it that I would like to recover, so I do not want to do a factory reset. What is the best thing to do here? Should I try to add it as a drive on a Windows computer? It does not show up in iTunes unless it is in DFU (recovery) mode.

How can I fix this?

EDIT 1 (7/26/23): I used [msftguy](http://msftguy.blogspot.com/)'s [SSH ramdisk tool](http://msftguy.blogspot.com/2012/01/automatic-ssh-ramdisk-creation-and.html) to back up the photos. The data volume was corrupted, so I had to use the command `mount_hfs -o rdonly /dev/disk0s2 /mnt2`. I have the download and the files needed  [here](https://github.com/cashiecoder/sshrd). It has to be used on a 32-bit machine. I have only tested it on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Would a backup software like [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) work?

Comment: There are two causes for a phone to not boot:  software failure or hardware failure.  If it’s the first, you just have to remove the Jailbreak with a backup image.  If it’s the second, like failed memory, there’s nothing you can do.  No software is going to be able to access a device that can’t boot.  If you can get it into DFU mode, you’ve got a chance.  Start by holding power and home (from off), after 10 seconds, release power but continue holding home.  It should be in DFU after about 20 seconds.  Let me know what happens.

Comment: I don't have a cable to test it with right now (my cat chewed through it a few months ago), but I am getting one soon. However, I think it went into DFU mode when I tried it last. I'm getting a cable in the next few days, so I'll get back to you.

Comment: No worries.  Those 30 pin cables are getting harder to find (people throw them away).  Just ping me here in comments when you post an update.

Comment: As soon as I get the cable I'll do an @Allan in the comments. You said "remove the Jailbreak with a backup image". Will this erase the phone? What kind of backup image do I use? I never took a backup of the phone. As I said, it was second hand and came to me jailbroken. Would I use an IPSW file?

Comment: DFU is recovery mode so it won’t be jailbroken anymore.  You’ll have to re-jailbreak if that’s what you want. Unfortunately, to fix this, you’ll have to go through these steps to get to a resolution.

Comment: Will this erase the data on it? I need the photos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147364/discussion-between-cashiecoder-and-allan).

Comment: You might be able to break the Recovery Mode boot loop.  Download the [redsn0w utility](https://redsn0w.en.lo4d.com/screenshots) and select the “recovery fix” option.

Comment: @Allan I am on redsn0w and am doing this now, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @Allan! The phone shows up in redsn0w in DFU mode, but every time I try to do the recovery fix option I get "USB communication error". I have tried using multiple versions of the app, using different USB ports, disabling antivirus, restarting, and nothing fixes it. Any ideas?

Comment: It’s more and more likely to be a hardware issue with the iPhone and not your computer.  If you can get your hands on a *working* iPhone 4s or earlier to test with, if you can communicate with that but not with your 3G, the issue will narrow itself down to the 3G being at fault.

Comment: @Allan I found the problem. I was using a too-new version of redsn0w. Now when I open redsn0w I have recovery fix grayed out. I am trying to do the just boot but it hangs on waiting for reboot. I tried the pull plug and plug back in trick (https://realitypod.com/story/redsn0w-fix-waiting-for-reboot/).

Comment: @Allan, I talked to my mom and she said that it was an untethered jailbreak. I found an older version of redsn0w and it did not have the recovery fix grayed out. I ran it and I got "Internal error". I just don't know what to do now. I think I've tried everything. Can I remove the chip from inside the iPhone? I know that's probably not feasible but it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: You can try sending it to an iPhone data recovery place, but if the storage is faulty, it’s not likely to be successful.  I don’t know of any that work on jailbroken devices, though.

Comment: I found a utility that was designed for old jailbroken iPhones to recover data, I am trying it tomorrow or the next day. I'll get back to you on it. The link is [here](http://msftguy.blogspot.com/2012/01/automatic-ssh-ramdisk-creation-and.html).

Comment: Hi @Allan! I used that utility I mentioned in my previous post to get the photos off! It worked perfectly. If you want to leave a response about redsn0w I'll mark it as correct and you can get the +100 point bounty. Thank you for all of your support with this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>I’m writing this as a canonical answer so that it can help point others in a direction to help them if they encounter a similar situation</sup>

#### Boot Loop/Failure

If you phone is stuck in a boot loop or it crashes before it gets to the home screen, there are two conditions that will cause this:

- Hardware failure
- Software/filesystem corruption

In the case of hardware, this could be anything from the memory (RAM), the storage (NAND flash) and even the CPU.  If this is the case, there’s not much you can do, especially from a DIY perspective.  You might have some luck sending it in to a data recovery service.

In the case of software or a filesystem corruption, the easiest fix is to put the device into DFU mode (hold power and home for iPhone 3G) and restore from backup

#### Jailbroken Devices

The pineapple boot logo indicate that this was broken using the [Redsn0w Jailbreak Utility](https://www.techjunkie.com/redsn0w-redsnow-jailbreak-download-with-links/) developed by the [iPhone Dev Team](https://www.iphwn.org/).  In addition to being able to jailbreak your phone, it includes a recovery utility to fix boot problems.

With extensive work by the OP, it was determined that you have to download the correct version of the utility for your particular device.  This requires some trial and error. Redsn0w also has to be run in Windows XP Compatibility Mode.